# Объясните классы в С++

Tags: c++, функции, классы, наследование

Даны такие классы:

```
class A {

    public:

        virtual void foo() { cout << "Call foo from A" << endl; }

        void bar() { cout << "Call bar from A" << endl; }
};

class B : public A {

    public:

        void foo() { cout << "Call foo from B" << endl; }

        virtual void bar() { cout << "Call bar from B" << endl; }
};

int main() {

    A* pA = new B();

    pA->foo();

    pA->bar();

    delete pA;
}
```

Код работает, но в код не полный, надо его изменить, исправить.

Comment: "Что будет выведено на консоль?" - это наивность или наглость?

Comment: Просто я не удачно переустановил Visual Studio, а ответ срочно понадобился)

Comment: "The dog ate my homework."

Comment: Все хуже, сессия))

Comment: НаучИтесь работать с MinGW, ему даже установка не требуется. Распаковать да путь до бинарников в `PATH` добавить...

Comment: Будет время - сделаю))

Comment: Тут опущены такие строчки, с которыми неясно, их не включили вопрос из ненадобности (т. к. они очевидны), или вопрос как раз о них.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приведенном коде не хватает виртуального деструктора.

На консоль будет выведено

```
Call foo from B
Call bar from A
```

Comment: А чем в **данном случае** грозит невиртуальный деструктор?

Comment: @kff Неопределенным поведением.

Comment: Вызовется автогенерированный деструктор базового класса?

Comment: @kff Да, вызовется. Если я не ошибаюсь, то в стандарте не говорится об исключении для этого частного случая, когда классы пустые.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо. P.S. Глубоких знаний не хватает...

Comment: @kff Мне тоже не хватает.:)

Comment: Слово virtual в этом коде никакой роли не играет

Comment: @BuilderC а поподробней можете объяснить?